# Geb how to reference a module from another module?

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I am attempting to reference a module from inside another module and it is not working as expected. I am not sure where I have gone wrong so I will let my code example/stack trace do the talking.

Main Test Spec:

```
class TestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
//bunch of code yada yada
    def "someFeatureMethod"(){
        at Page1
        module1.doThing()
    }
}
```

Here is what Page1 looks like:

```
class Page1 extends Page {
    static content = {
        module1 { module(new Module1())}
    }
}
```

Here is what Module1 looks like:

```
class Module1 extends Module{
    static content = {
        module2 {module(new Module2())} //not going to type it out but assume module2 has a method named someFunction2()
    }

    def doThing(){
        //This is where I am unsure the most. I have tried a few different things in this section
        browser.at Page1
        module1.module2.someFunction2()
    }
}
```

My stack trace is something like this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unable to resolve module1 as content for Page1 -> module1: Module1, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is module1 a class you forgot to import?
```

I did import everything I possibly could.

All I want is to be able to have a module inside a module if this is possible, please explain how it is implemented thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax in the doThing() method is as follows:

```
def doThing(){
    module2.someFunction2()
}
```

I actually had a type-o when I tried this earlier which is why I was so confused. after fixing the type-o I tested and this setup works.